# Cache for Cakephp queries

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-2.5

I want to implement a cache functionnality for cakephp 2.5.3, related to find queries, but I want to invalidate cache on all events related to the tables (update, delete, ...).
I coded this into AppModel.php, can you tell me what do you think about the code logic and efficiency ?
Thanks.

```
public function find($conditions = null, $fields = array(), $order = null, $recursive = null) {
    $keyName = sha1(serialize(func_get_args()));
    if (Cache::read($this->table . '_' . $keyName, '5m') !== false) {
        $this->log('read cache ' . $this->table . '_' . $keyName);

        return Cache::read($this->table . '_' . $keyName, '5m');
    } else {

        $data = parent::find($conditions, $fields, $order, $recursive);
        Cache::write($this->table . '_' . $keyName, $data, '5m');
        $this->addToCacheList($keyName);
        $this->log('add ' . $this->table . '_' . $keyName);

        return $data;
    }
}

public function afterSave($created, $options = array()) {

    $this->flushCacheList();

    parent::afterSave($created, $options);
}

public function afterDelete() {

    $this->flushCacheList();

    parent::afterDelete();
}

public function addToCacheList($keyName) {
    if (Cache::read($this->table, '5m') !== false) {
        $values = Cache::read($this->table, '5m');
        $values[] = $keyName;
    } else {
        $values = array($keyName);
    }

    Cache::write($this->table, $values, '5m');
}

public function flushCacheList() {
    if (Cache::read($this->table, '5m')) {
        $values = Cache::read($this->table, '5m');
        foreach($values AS $value) {
            Cache::delete($this->table . '_' . $value, '5m');
            $this->log('flush ' . $this->table . '_' . $value);
        }
        Cache::delete($this->table, '5m');
    }
}
```

Comment: zeflex, Whats the error?? can you explain of error??

Answer (score 0):

CakePHP has already [a built in query cache](http://api.cakephp.org/2.5/source-class-Model.html#265).

> what do you think about the code logic and efficiency ?

I'm not sure but I think you flush the cache too often to be efficient.

Don't think about performance *benchmark* it. The only reliable way is a benchmark.

But I would say [cache the results of queries instead.](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/caching.html#using-cache-to-store-common-query-results)

Comment: I saw http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/caching.html#using-cache-to-store-common-query-results but there, you are not invalidating the cache on update/save/delete operations. That's why I implemented this as I didn't find something similar. When you say I flush the cache too often, I will tell yes and no. I want to get the freshest results available after any operations on any table.